# Writing files in Cordova/ionic doesn't work

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm writing an app using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)/[ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and I'm now trying to write files to the filesystem using the [$cordovaFile plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/). So I try exactly the code from the docs (with some added logging):

```
$cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "file.txt", "the text inside the file", true)
    .then(function (success) {
        console.log('SUCCESS: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

but this returns `ERROR: {"code":5}` in which `5` refers to an `ENCODING_ERR`.

So after trying some different combinations, changing the first line to this (so without the dir):

```
$cordovaFile.writeFile("file14.txt", "text", true)
```

returns (formatted for readability):

```
SUCCESS: {
    "type": "writeend",
    "bubbles": false,
    "cancelBubble": false,
    "cancelable": false,
    "lengthComputable": false,
    "loaded": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "target": "fileName": "",
    "length": 4,
    "localURL": "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/file14.txt",
    "position": 4,
    "readyState": 2,
    "result": null,
    "error": null,
    "onwritestart": null,
    "onprogress": null,
    "onwrite": null,
    "onabort": null,
    "onerror": null
}
```

So I try reading out this same file using:

```
$cordovaFile.readAsText("file14.txt")
    .then(function (success) {
        console.log('SUCCESS: ' + JSON.stringify(success));
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

which to my surprise just returns an empty string: `SUCCESS: ""`

So I'm now wondering:

1. Why does copy-pasting the example code lead to a `5 ENCODING_ERR`?
2. Why does it work when I eliminate the dir?
3. How can I read out the file I've just created?

Comment: why not use cordova native file system ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek - I'm not sure what you mean. The plugin I se is this one: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file and I can't find any other one. Any tips maybe?

Comment: @karmer65 yes this is the one i mean latest version is 1.3.3 , why are you using success function as an object , i think you are confused between sucess data , and sucess function.

Comment: I've got a similar error. I created a file in path `..\Phone\Android\data\com.ionicframework.appname761153\files` called test.txt. it *succeeded* as i saw in debugging (via USB directly from Android Device) but there is no such file in the Folder.

Answer (score 0):

This **[tutorial](http://qnimate.com/working-with-file-system-using-intel-xdk/)** is easy to follow , it works on intel xdk but it uses cordova , so simply will work as long as you have cordova ( it has nothing to do with intel xdk api ) , just make sure the `cordova.file` object is defined in your code .

Please note that there are dramatic change in cordova file system starting from ver 1.2 , also please note that current ver 1.3.3 have some bugs regarding loading files from your current workspace ( www folder ) , however writing and read files to and from application storage folder or internal storage dont have any issues.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() 
        {
            requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);
        }

        function onSuccess(fileSystem) 
        {   
            var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;

            //lets create a file named readme.txt. getFile method actually creates a file and returns a pointer(FileEntry) if it doesn't exist otherwise just returns a pointer to it. It returns the file pointer as callback parameter.
            directoryEntry.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry){
                //lets write something into the file
                fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer){
                    writer.write("This is the text inside readme file");
                }, function(error){
                    console.log("Error occurred while writing to file. Error code is: " + error.code);
                });
            }, function(error){
                console.log("Error occurred while getting a pointer to file. Error code is: " + error.code);
            });
        }

        function onError(evt)
        {
            console.log("Error occurred during request to file system pointer. Error code is: " + evt.code);
        }
```